# How can I sound more 'native'?

Tags: learning-methods, self-learning, russian, french, informal-learning

I'm fluent in French and Russian - by which I mean that I don't have any trouble reading novels and can easily converse in either without making grammatical errors or feeling uncomfortable - and have been learning them for 2 and 3 years respectively.

Yet whenever I speak either with a native speaker (which, I should add is a rather rare occurrence) I am told that I speak like a foreigner, i.e. I don't use the right slang, etc.

Now it's hardly surprising, but something I feel rather uncomfortable about.

So, given that conversing with native speakers is a rather rare luxury for me, what can I do to make myself sound less 'foreigner-y'?

Comment: What is your native language, and do you care about accent reduction, too?

Comment: @AML My native language is English, and I'm not really concerned about my accent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think [this](https://www.5minutelanguage.com/how-to-sound-like-a-native-speaker-in-a-foreign-language/) article has a lot of good tips for you. Even though some of the tips are about accent, many of the tips aren't. And frankly, if you want to sound like a native, then accent is absolutely part of the equation, so I wouldn't disregard it if I were you.

In addition to your clear need for speaking to a variety of natives in order to increase your exposure to the language, you should also:

1. Analyze spoken language and figure out how natives say the things you want to say
2. Use [connectors](https://www.fluentin3months.com/conversational-connectors-how-to-fake-having-a-conversation-just-after-starting-to-learn-a-language/)
3. Use French and Russian-specific [fillers](https://www.lingholic.com/so-are-fillers-okay-to-use-when-um-learning-a-foreign-language/)
4. Make sure you speak in the correct register/level of formality, i.e., don't speak formally all the time.
5. Learn and use age-appropriate slang